# MySQL imported wrong datatype into a VARCHAR column

Tags: mysql, database, csv, sqldatatypes

Today I did something stupid: I had a list of card numbers in an excel file that I had to import to a DB table somehow. So i exported the numbers to CSV file, but *without any quotes* (don't ask me why). The file looked like:

```
123456
234567
345678
...
```

Then I created a table with a single `VARCHAR(22)` column and did a

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'numbers.csv' INTO TABLE cards
```

This worked fine, apart from many warnings, which I ignored (the other stupid thing I did).
After that I tried to query with this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM cards WHERE number='123456'
```

which gave me an empty result. Whereas this works:

```
SELECT * FROM cards WHERE number=123456
```

Notice the missing quotes! So it seems, that I managed to populate my `VARCHAR` table with `INTEGER` data. I have no idea how that is possible at all.

I already tried to fix this with an `UPDATE` like this

```
UPDATE cards SET number = CAST(number AS CHAR(22))
```

But that didn't work.

So is there a way to fix this and how could this even happen?

Comment: Is it posible you have spaces in your field? These would be stripped when doing numeric conversion as far as I know. If it's a `VARCHAR` column it will contain only character data, not integers, but some implicit conversion may be done when doing filtering. What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE cards` show?

Comment: I figured out what really happened after i exported the data. There's a hidden `\r` appended to each value! It's still weird though, why the query worked without quotes.

Comment: It's because of the implicit conversion. It causes a cast on the values to do a numeric comparison. You should add an answer on how to fix this. When doing your import, don't forget `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`. If you're ever confused about what's in a field, including hidden characters, try `SELECT HEX(number) FROM cards`.

Comment: That makes sense. So after the conversion the `\r` is stripped off, whereas if i do a quoted query it will try an exact match, which fails. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of some implicit conversion in order to do a numerical comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM cards WHERE number='123'
```

This will only match against text fields that are literally `"123"` and will miss on `" 123"` and `"123\r"` if you have those. For some reason, `"123 "` and `"123"` are considered "equivalent" presumably do to trailing space removal on both sides.

When doing your import, don't forget `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`. If you're ever confused about what's in a field, including hidden characters, try:

```
SELECT HEX(number) FROM cards
```

This will show the hex-dumped output of each string. Things like `20` indicate space, just as `%20` in a URL is a space.

You can also fix this by:

```
UPDATE cards SET number=REPLACE(number, '\r', '')
```